# Blake2 installation in linux?

Tags: hashing

I was trying to install from source BLAKE2 hash function in Ubuntu, but I do not know how. I don`t know how to use these makefiles with .c and .h files . Any help? https://blake2.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the README document file?,it has the proper description of all folders inside it.

> In my debian I just make:
>
> 1. unzip blake2_code_20140114.zip
> 2. cd blake2_code_20140114
> 3. cd sse or ref (it really depends on the implementation that you want)
> 4. make (check this file if you want other options)

#### C implementations of blake2b, blake2bp, blake2s, blake2sp, optimized for speed on CPUs supporting SSE2, SSSE3, SSE4.1, AVX, or XOP

Comment: Yes, but I am able to use that program just in that folder, I don't have global supported command in terminal like md5sum or sha256 after installing rhash program.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to obtain the software, binaries can be downloaded here:

https://blake2.net/b2sum-bin_20130305.zip (BLAKE2)

or

https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/releases (BLAKE3)

If you wish to compile the code, then you will need to first verify that you have the appropriate development tools installed (eg. gcc). Installing these will depend on the Linux distribution you are using. On Debian based distributions (such as Ubuntu) you can install the "build-essential" package, and on CentOS there is the "Development Tools" group.

I will refer to the contents in the most recent git tag:

https://codeload.github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/zip/20190724

for the following. The code first needs to be extracted, which can be done by running:

```
unzip BLAKE2-20190724.zip
```

This extracts the zip file to the current directory. Then have a look at at the README. It describes the contents of the directories. You will use the makefile in the directory containing the software you desire. For example, to build b2sum run:

```
cd BLAKE2-20190724/b2sum
make
sudo make install
```

which should show output similar to:

```
$ make
cc b2sum.c ../sse/blake2b.c ../sse/blake2s.c ../sse/blake2bp.c ../sse/blake2sp.c  -O3 -march=native -Werror=declaration-after-statement -std=c99 -I../sse -fopenmp  -o b2sum
$ sudo make install
install -d /usr/local/bin
install -d /usr/local/man/man1
install -m 755 b2sum /usr/local/bin
install -m 644 b2sum.1 /usr/local/man/man1/b2sum.1
```

and you should now have a b2sum executable you can run!

As noted by AAAfarmclub in the comments, there is now a BLAKE3. If you want to build it yourself you can obtain the code here:

https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

or from the releases page referenced above.

Comment: There's a Blake3 now: https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3

Answer (score 0):

#Missing blake2

Get from
https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2

copy download zip link address to clipboard  https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

```
cd /home/user
mkdir blake2
cd blake2
wget https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
ls --> master.zip
sudo apt-get install unzip
unzip master.zip
ls --> BLAKE2.master   master.zip
cd /BLAKE2.master/b2sum
make 
sudo make instal
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).